# Sending emails via HTML form webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm developing a simple form with a text box and submit button.
How can I arrange it so that when the submit button is pushed the data is sent via email?

Any help is much apprechiated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using InfoPath forms?Please explain how you are "developing" forms

Comment: I am using the HTML form editor web part on sharepoint. I have been told not to use Infopath by my manager.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi Hugh, I don't have enough score to post a comment for the author's post.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, Please use this code <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT EMAIL TO: email address" <a href="mailto:email address">